# Image URL with session string

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I cannot display images in my application when I have the session string in the URL.

This works:
http://server/application/image.png

This doesn't:
http://server/application/(S(ane2sz55z15ra045gocejcq1))/image.png

It worked fine when it was running in Windows XP, but now I have moved it to Windows Server 2008 instead. The same happens with CSS and JS files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running the application pool in Integrated Mode all requests are passed through the asp.net pipeline. Under Advanced Settings in your application pool, check if the application pool runs in Integrated Mode. However, if the App pool runs in Classic Mode, make sure .png is mapped to aspnetisapi.dll or aspnetisapi64.dll.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the .PNG extention isn't mapped to ASP.Net, and therefore your webserver will try and serve it as static content, which of course doesn't exist.

Comment: Is it only Windows Server that doesn't have this mapping as default?

How can I set this mapping?